# Iterate over every black square of a "chessboard"

Tags: python, loops

I'd like to iterate over every other element of a `m`-by-`n` "chessboard", i.e.,

```
l = []
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        if (i+j) % 2 == 0:
            l.append(something(i, j))
```

I'm using an explicit loop here, but for speed would rather use a list comprehension.

Any hints?

For bonus points, the solution also works for `i`, `j`, `k` with `(i+j+k) % 2 == 0`.

Comment: If you want to handle an arbitrary number of axes, look into `itertools.product`, but note that *"any ideas?"* isn't a good SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, list comprehension is just like your nested `for` loop, except that this is done *within* the list brackets:

```
my_list = [something(i, j) for i in range(m) for j in range(n) if (i + j) % 2 == 0]
```

More generally, for `n` nested loops, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), like this:

```
from itertools import product

my_list = [something(*p) for p in product(range(n), repeat=n) if sum(p) % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you would like an explicit expression for the x and y coordinates of the black squares on the 'chess board', so that you don't have to evaluate the boolean for every square. Here is an implementation of my solution (for a 2-dimensional board):

```
import numpy as np

# 'Chess board' dimension
m = 3       # Number of columns
n = 4       # Number of rows

# Counter variable. The length of this array is equal to the total number of black squares.
k = np.arange(0,m*n,2)

x_coords = (k + (k/n) % 2) % n      # x-coordinates of black squares
y_coords = (k + (k/n) % 2) / n      # y-coordinates of black squares

print("x-coordinates: "+str(x_coords))
print("y-coordinates: "+str(y_coords))
```

For the 3x4 dimensional board in the example above, this generates the following output:

```
x-coordinates: [0 2 1 3 0 2]
y-coordinates: [0 0 1 1 2 2]
```

which you can verify by drawing a little diagram. Note that the 'helper variable' `(k/n) % 2` keeps track of whether the row number is even or odd; the odd rows have an 'offset' with respect to the even ones.